# In Unity, how to disable enemies's friendly fire while not disabling my shots on enemy? I'm using only one script to the lase Shot

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My Player fires a laser, by instantiating a "laser prefab". The laser prefab has a "laser tag".
The enemy instantiate a prefab called "Enemy_lasers", that is composed by two of the "laser prefabs" mentioned earlier, so they also have the "laser tag" and they both use the same "laser script". When the enemy shots, sometimes it hits other enemies, destroying them like it was shot by the player. How to disable this? Is it better to do all with one script for all laser shots or should I use other scripts and other prefabs to enemy's laser shots? Using two scripts and two prefabs would be easier, I guess, but I don't know if it is the best solution

**Laser Script**

```
    private float _speedLaser = 10.0f;

    private bool _isEnemyLaser = false;

    void Update()
    {
       if (_isEnemyLaser == false)
        {
            MoveUp();
        }

       else if (_isEnemyLaser == true)
        {
            MoveDown();
        }
    }

    void MoveUp()
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector3.up * _speedLaser * Time.deltaTime);
        if (transform.position.y > 5.4f)
        {
            if (transform.parent != null)
            {
                Destroy(transform.parent.gameObject);
            }
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }
    }

    void MoveDown()
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector3.down * _speedLaser * Time.deltaTime);
        if (transform.position.y < -5.5f)
        {
            if (transform.parent != null)
            {
                Destroy(transform.parent.gameObject);
            }
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }
    }

    public void AssignEnemy()
    {
        _isEnemyLaser = true;   
    }
     }
```

**Enemy Script:**

```
 public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
    {
    [SerializeField]
    private float _speedEnemy = 6.0f;    
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject _enemy_explosionPrefab;
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject _laserPrefab;

    private float _FireRate = 3.0f;
    private float _canFire = -1f;  
    private UIManager _uiManager;
    private GameManager _gameManager;
   

    
    void Update()
    {
        Movement();

        if (Time.time > _canFire)
        {
            _FireRate = Random.Range(3f, 8f);
            _canFire = Time.time + _FireRate;
            GameObject enemylaser = Instantiate(_laserPrefab, transform.position + new Vector3 (0, -0.52f, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            Laser[] lasers = enemylaser.GetComponentsInChildren<Laser>();

            for (int i =0; i < lasers.Length; i++)
            {
                lasers[i].AssignEnemy();
            }
            
        }

       
    }

 

   


    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Player")
        {
            Player player = other.transform.GetComponent<Player>();
            if (player != null)
            {
                _uiManager.PenaltyScore();
                player.Damage();
            }
            Instantiate(_enemy_explosionPrefab, transform.position + new Vector3 (0, -0.51f, 0), Quaternion.identity);  
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }

        if (other.tag == "Laser" && transform.position.y < 6.2f)
        {
                        
            Destroy(other.gameObject);
            _uiManager.UpdateScore();
            Instantiate(_enemy_explosionPrefab, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
            
            
        }
    }


   
}
```

I tried using a tag in the "enemy_laser", which is the father/container of two "laser prefabs", by using the code:

```
    if (other.tag == "Laser" && transform.position.y < 6.2f && other.transform.parent.tag = "EnemyLaserShot")
        {
                        
            Destroy(other.gameObject);
            _uiManager.UpdateScore();
            Instantiate(_enemy_explosionPrefab, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
            
            
        }
```

But this just desactivated all of the laser shots, including my player's laser shots against the enemies.

Comment: I think it should be `other.gameObject.transform.parent.tag`. And also you should use `==` to check parent tag.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two solutions:

1. You can associate one public boolean variable with your laser `firedByPlayer` which will be true when fired by player. Then, in your enemy controller script just get the gameobject of laser and check for that boolean variable value.
2. Introduce another tag `LaserFromEnemy` which will be associated with laser fired by an enemy.

I will prefer second solution, looks better.

Comment: I tried the second one by adding "EnemyLaser", assingned it to the "Enemy_laser prefab", which contains two prefabs with "laser tag" and I couldn't hit enemies with my player. I added this to the if:

    ´´´ if (other.tag == "Laser" && transform.position.y < 6.2f && other.transform.parent.tag != "Tag Name")
´´´

Comment: I tried now, It worked the first time, but the next it just disable my player's laser shots

Comment: Can you edit the question and add what you tried?

Comment: My coide was:


`   if (other.tag == "Laser" && transform.position.y < 6.2f && other.transform.parent.tag = "EnemyLaserShot")
        {
                        
            Destroy(other.gameObject);
            _uiManager.UpdateScore();
            Instantiate(_enemy_explosionPrefab, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
            
            
        }`

Comment: Done, edited with more informations

Comment: Please see my comment in the question above.

Answer (score 0):

You could expose the `IsEnemyLaser` flag and ignore that laser in that case.

In general I would refactor your `Laser` script a little as it has some redundancy

```
[SerializeField] private float _speedLaser = 10.0f;

// public read-only access
public bool IsEnemyLaser { get; private set; }

private void Update()
{
    Move();
}

void Move()
{
    var direction = IsEnemyLaser ? Vector3.down : Vector3.up;
    transform.Translate(direction * _speedLaser * Time.deltaTime);

    var reachedLimit = IsEnemyLaser ? transform.position.y < -5.5f : transform.position.y > 5.4f;

    if (reachedLimit)
    {
        if (transform.parent)
        {
            Destroy(transform.parent.gameObject);
        }
        else
        {
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }
    }
}

public void AssignEnemy()
{
    IsEnemyLaser = true;   
}
```

**Note though**: In general if using physics you should not move objects through `transform` which might break collision detection. Rather go through `Rigidbody2D` in that case.

And now in your other script you can simply check for the components instead of using tags at all and do e.g.

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.TryGetComponent<Player>(out var player))
    {
        _uiManager.PenaltyScore();
        player.Damage();
        Instantiate(_enemy_explosionPrefab, transform.position + new Vector3 (0, -0.51f, 0), Quaternion.identity);  
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }
    else if (other.TryGetComponent<Laser>(out var laser) && !laser.IsEnemyLaser)
    {                  
        Destroy(other.gameObject);
        _uiManager.UpdateScore();
        Instantiate(_enemy_explosionPrefab, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        Destroy(this.gameObject);         
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I'm still far bellow this level  of coding
I dont get the ? symbol and the : as well in
 `IsEnemyLaser ? Vector3.down : Vector3.up;`

Also TryGetComponent and how out works

Comment: I searched and got easily the ? operator, but still trying to figure how out var works

Comment: `var direction = IsEnemyLaser ? Vector3.down : Vector3.up;` basically is just a shorthand for writing `Vector3 direction; if(IsEnemyLaser) { direction = Vector3.down; } else { direction = Vector3.up; }` ;) See [ternary operator `?`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator)

Comment: Also [`TryGetComponent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.TryGetComponent.html) is basically just yet another shorthand (you know we programmers are "lazy" ;) ) and replaces/combines doing e.g. `if (other.TryGetComponent<Player>(out var player)) { ... }` instead of `var player = other.GetComponent<Player>(); if(player != null) { ... }` .. it just makes the code easier and cleaner and you ca directly use an exclusive `if else`